# NVD3 - removing options for stackedAreaChart

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

I'm using the [stacked area chart](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/stackedArea.html) in NVD3, but I don't want it to show the three options for Stacked, Stream, and Expanded.

Is there a flag I can pass to remove the UI element to switch between them and pick which one to use?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass `.showControls(false)` to the model to disable this.

Comment: If any ``rCharts`` users come here, if n is your nPlot,  do ``n$chart(style = 'stack')`` followed by ``n$chart(showControls = FALSE)``, to get the above with the default 'stack' selected. The other two are 'stream' and 'expand'.

Answer (score 5):

```
 $scope.options = {
            chart: {
               ..
                showControls: false,
                }
        };
```

Add   `showControls: false  ,` to your options

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you're using angular-nvd3, you can use CSS.

```
svg {
    .nv-controlsWrap {
        display: none;
    }
}
```