# nvd3 remove stream option

Tags: d3.js, visualization, data-visualization, nvd3.js

I'm using the stacked area chart in NVD3. By default, it has the control options "Stacked, Stream, and Expanded", (see chart in this related, but not identical question: [NVD3 - removing options for stackedAreaChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432486/nvd3-removing-options-for-stackedareachart)).

I would like only the two options "Stacked" and "Expanded" to appear. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no option to disable just that, but you can remove the control after the graph has been drawn:

```
d3.selectAll("g.nv-series")
  .filter(function() {
    return d3.select(this).select("text").text() == "Stream";
  })
  .remove();
```

This will leave a gap where the control used to be, which you could adjust by selecting the other element and changing its position in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks. It works when the chart is drawn the first time, but if the window is resized later, the "Stream" option reappears.

Comment: Great. I changed nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update); to nv.utils.windowResize(update_cust); where the function update_cust contains chart.update as well as the code you proposed above.

Comment: @jaweej Can you show exactly how that funtion looks? am in a similar predicament

Answer (score 4):

```
chart._options.controlOptions = ['Stacked', 'Expanded'];
```

[How to Remove control options from NVD3.js Stacked Area Chart](http://www.bainweb.com/2015/09/how-to-remove-control-options-from.html)

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to use the option `controlOptions`

```
chart: {
    ...
    controlOptions: ['Stacked', 'Expanded'],
    controlLabels: {"stacked": "Default", "expanded": "Percentage"},
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `chart.controlOptions(["Stacked","Expanded"]);` for more information https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#stackedAreaChart